# Использование отдельного CSS файла для Header в Ruby on Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

Проект на Рельсах. Подключен Bootstrap.
Делаю отдельно Header для сайта. Но как использовать css файл только для Header?

В папке `/app/views/layout` создал `_header.html.erb` где сама структура меню.

В папку `/app/assets/stylesheets` файл `header.scss`

В `/config/initializers/assets.rb` добавил `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( header.css )`

В `application.html.erb` добавил `<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'header' %>`.

Рендерится в `application.html.erb`:

```
<body>
<%= render 'layouts/header' %>
<div class="container">
    <%= yield %>
</div>
<%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
```

CSS файл работает, но работает для всего сайта, а не для Header. Как заставить рендерить `layouts/header` вместе с файлом `header.scss`?

Comment: Вы хотите применять некий CSS-файл только к куску страницы? Так что ли?

Comment: Да, именно так и хочу. Применять отдельный CSS файл допустим только для footer или header

Comment: Тогда никак. CSS если присутствует, то действует на всю страницу. [Скоупинг из спецификации вышвырнули.](https://caniuse.com/#feat=style-scoped) Используйте селекторы CSS.

Comment: Так и сделал. Спасибо за ответ!